# jquery animate scroll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I want to make scroll effect with button to my content. Maybe anyone can fix my code and explain why it is not working? Thank you !

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="main">
<section class="section home">
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#home-content" class="scroll">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content" id="home-content">
        <p>
            My content
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

My js file:
 `

```
function scrollDown () {
        $('a[href="scroll"]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var targetOffset = $('a[class="content"]').offset().top;
            $('.main').animate({
                scrollTop: targetOffset
            },1000);

        }); 
    }
```

`

Comment: `$('a.scroll')` use this.

Comment: i tried all of these calls, still doesn't work.

Comment: What libraries are you including?  I mean, do you reference just jQuery, or also jQueryUI?

Comment: Are you sure, this function is registered? Try adding an alert inside the function and see if at least the function is getting called. My intuition says that its not getting attached to the button link. Try putting the function inside `$(document).ready();`

Comment: I'm using only jQuery library

Comment: Do you call `scrollDown`? Do you `.main` have an `overflow: auto;` to make it scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo that shows how you can cause your button to scroll the window down to your content when pressed. It adds a margin-top to your content to push it below the bottom of the viewport, so that it can showcase the scrolling action.

To get it working, I needed to remove your `scrollDown` function, change some of your jQuery selectors, and animate the scrollTop on `html, body`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$('a.scroll').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetOffset = $('div.content').offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: targetOffset + "px"
    },1000);
});
```

```css
.content {
    margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<section class="section home">
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#home-content" class="scroll">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content" id="home-content">
        <p>
            My content
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu aliquam sapien, nec accumsan odio. Nunc ac purus accumsan augue sodales malesuada ut at ipsum. Curabitur volutpat et risus ut ultrices. Fusce ante sapien, laoreet non scelerisque nec, elementum et nisl. Curabitur pharetra a sapien ac convallis. Aliquam dapibus viverra sem a lacinia. Proin tempor orci nec massa feugiat, ac tristique tellus convallis.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/vhaye0c0/1/

Comment: Thank you very much ! i didn't see this mistake with my selector !